Determine whether the Fourier coefficients coincide.
I have the following problem:
Let $f$, $g \in L^2(\mathbb{T})$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure, with Fourier series
$
f(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty} \alpha_n e^{inx}
$
and
$
g(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n=+\infty} \beta_n e^{inx}
$
such that there exist natural numbers $n_0$ and $n_1$ with $\alpha_n = 0$ for $n \geq n_0$ and $\beta_n = 0$ for $n \geq n_1$, and $f = g$ on a set of positive measure. Determine whether the Fourier coefficients coincide.
Well, I have tried to prove it with different tools: in terms of getting power series and their conjugates, applying the Principle of analytical prolongation, by proving that in the set where $f=g$ there are accumulation points,..., in fact, I have also read that A. Zygmund proved (1948) that if the sums of two lacunary trigonometric series coincide on a set of positive measure, then these series are identical, but the series of this problem are not strictly lacunary trigonometric series (plus I can't find Zydmund's proof).
The problem is proving more difficult than I thought. I would be grateful if someone could give it a try, because I have a suspicion that the coefficients are going to coincide.

this actually predates Zygmund and has been originally proven by Fatou in this case (and generalized by Privalov), namely that if two well-behaved analytic functions in the unit disc (eg $H^2$) have nontangential limit that coincide on a set of positive circle measure, then they are equal but the proof requires some theory - the coolest is by Helson and I reproduced it here (for bounded functions but the proof only uses that they are $L^2$) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3571028/complex-analysis-showing-analytic-function-is-zero?noredirect=1

note that if the circle set is regular (eg an arc) much simpler proofs using Schwarz reflection are possible and of course the condition $\alpha_n = \beta_n= 0, n \ge n_0$ is crucial as otherwise there are functions that are not identically zero but zero on an arc like the characteristic function of any arc - those however have nonzero Fourier coefficients of arbitrary high positive and negative indices

@Conrad I had also tried taking the difference, expressing everything in terms of $\bar{z}=e^{-i\theta}$ and multiply $(\bar{z})^N$ to get a power series $\sum a_n(\bar{z})^n$ and then taking the conjugate to get an analytic function $\sum \bar{a_n}z^n$ in the disc that is $0$ (non-tangentially) on a zero measure set of the unit disc, but I do not know how to follow. If someone could give me step by step instructions so that I don't get lost, I would be very grateful

check my answer in the linked question above for what is probably the simplest proof (due originally to Helson)

You've written $f$ and $g$ as functions of $x$ on one side of the equation and as functions of $t$ on the other.

you are right @JohnBarber !!! It was my mistake while was writing the post. I have corrected it, thank you so so so much

Well, @Conrad . I have read it, but I do not know how to link my problem with the problem you solved

Not sure what is the issue - just take $\bar z^N (f-g)$ for a large $N$ to get an anti-analytic function with $L^2$ boundary limits zero on a set of nonzero measure and then by conjugation you get an analytic $h$ with same property; from there the proof applies word for word, first you make the free term on the circle nonzero by an appropriate multiplication then consider the closed convex space in $L^2$ as there, take its minimal element and show that its modulus has zero Fourier coefficients except the free term so is constant ae - it vanishes where $h$ did so it is zero ae - contradiction

I have posted the answer! I think it is already correct. Could you take a look, please? @Conrad
